# Searching In c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, search, console-application

i want to searching with ID in this Code 
when the user write the id the information of this ID ( title , name , phone) display 
How can i implement it ?

```
namespace Search
{
 class Program
 {
     static void InputStudent(Student x)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a User:");
        Console.WriteLine("User ID:");
        x.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Titel:");
        x.Titel = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        x.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Telephone Number:");
        x.Telephone = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();  
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Student[] st = new Student[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
        {
            st[i] = new Student();
            InputStudent(st[i]);
        }

        int IDs;
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of ID you want to search for ");
        IDs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Look up `FirstOrDefault` on MSDN. Have you tried anything?

Comment: And do not use arrays but a `List<Student>`

Comment: i know but But i was required to use arrays in this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ, for example `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`:

```
Student firstWithID = st.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == IDs);
if( firstWithID != null )
{
    Console.WriteLine("User ID: {0} Titel: {1} Name: {2} Telephone Number: {3}"
        , firstWithID.ID
        , firstWithID.Titel
        , firstWithID.Name
        , firstWithID.Telephone);
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file.